# How do I nest multiple <%= value %> inside <%= %>

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Rookie here, :) I have made an object **people** and referred it to **profile.ejs** as **people**:

```
app.get('/profile/:id',(req,res)=> {
      var people = {
        number: 3,
        men: [{name: 'Bruce', job: 'Batman'},
              {name: 'Jack', job: 'Samurai'},
              {name: 'Bane', job: 'Janitor'}]
      };
  res.render('profile.ejs',{id: req.params.id, people: people});
});
```

Then when I try to template it like this it didn't work:

```
    <p>of User..<%= id %></p>
    <p><strong> name : </strong> <%= people.men[(<%= id%>)].name %></p>
    <p><strong>job  : </strong> <%= people.men[(<%= id%>)].job %> </p>
```

I am getting an error:
**Error: Could not find a matching close tag for "<%=".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are inside some loop, no need to have extra `<%=` for id

```
 <p>of User..<%= id %></p>
 <p><strong> name : </strong> <%= people.men[id].name %></p>
 <p><strong>job  : </strong> <%= people.men[id].job %> </p>
```